# how to write result in f.write()

Tags: python, fwrite, radix-sort

I write a program for radix sort some numbers which is in a file.
here is my code:

```
rsort(a):
    if a:
        bins = [ [],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[] ]
        m = max(a)
        r = 1
        while m > r:
            for e in a:
                bins[(e/r)%10].append(e)
            r = r * 10
            a = []
            for i in range(10):
                a.extend(bins[i])
                bins[i] = []
        return a

def readfile(infile):
  grid = []
  f = open(infile, 'r')
  lines = f.readlines()
  f.close()
  return grid

def writefile(outfile):
    grid = []
    f = open(outfile, 'w')
    f.write()
    f.close
    return grid

def main():
    infile = readfile("radix.in")
    outfile = writefile("radix.out")
    sortedvar = rsort(infile)
main()
```

So, i tried plug in rsort() and rsort(a) in the f.write(), it keeps telling me wrong. and if i leave it empty, it tells me function need takes exactly 1 argument. what i should do to print the radix sort results in file radix.out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't look at the rsort function at all as your question seems to be about I/O and function calling in general. Here's a possibility (assuming the numbers are all on the first line).

```
def readfile(infile):
  nums = []
  f = open(infile, "r")
  line = f.readline()
  f.close()
  return [int(x) for x in line.split()]

def writefile(outfile, nums):
    f = open(outfile, 'w')
    f.write(' '.join([str(x) for x in nums]))
    f.write('\n')
    f.close()

def main():
    nums = readfile("radix.in")
#    nums = rsort(nums)
    writefile("radix.out", nums)

main()
```

Comment: hi, thank you! but the shell tells me "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '467 119 635 231 234 858\n'" is there other way to convert number to string?

Comment: @BengDai Then the numbers must all be on the same line. Try the updated code above.

Comment: ye! it works! but this is only work for all of numbers in one line right? how can i make it work with three lines? >_<